# Minimize the squared dot product of two specific vectors

Tags: optimization, algorithms, vectors, computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization

Do you think there exists a efficient algorithm(non brute-force) for the following problem. I search the optimal solution for the following problem:
Given a vector $u=(u_1, u_2,..., u_k)^T$ with $\forall u_i \in \mathbb{N}, i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$. I search a vector $v=(v_1, v_2, ..., v_k)^T$ with $\forall v_i \in \{1, -1\}, i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$, such that the squared dot product $(uv)^2$ is minimal. Another objective funktion could be the absoulte value of the dot produvt $|uv|$.
I have developed a algorithm that is based on a sorted list of $u_i$. But sadly this algorithm does not always calucluate the optimal value.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm not much used to work with vectors but I think that the vector form of Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality can be used to optimize the squared dot product of the vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, an NP-hard problem. It is a special case of the general quadratic maximization problem
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & v^T Q v \\
\text{subject to} & v_i^2 = 1, ~i=1,2,\dots, n
\end{array}
where, in this case, $Q=uu^T$. The class of problems for general $Q$ is of considerable academic and practical interest. I found [these lecture notes by Pablo Parillo at MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-972-algebraic-techniques-and-semidefinite-optimization-spring-2006/lecture-notes/lecture_03.pdf) that provide an overview of the problem an techniques for solving it approximately.

Comment: In the meantime I have recognized that this problem is very similar to the partition problem. Therefore I think there are good greedy algorithms or approximations available. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, the partition problem is closely related!